# Partial sum of square-free integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds, squarefree-numbers

I have been unable to find anywhere a sharp bounding for the partial sum of the first $n$ square-free integers $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k$, where $k$ runs over the square-free integers. I guess it should be around $\frac{\pi^2}{6} \left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right)$, but I found no reference to check and I do not have a rigorous way to prove my guess, just the heuristic following from the partial sum of the first positive integers and the distribution of square-free numbers.

Any reference or proof of a sharp bound would be welcomed.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

After some trial an error experimentation, it seems that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right)-\frac{6}{\pi^2}n\frac{\log(n)}{\log\log(n)}+O\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{\log\log(n)}}\right)$$ Here the graphical representation of the diferences between $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k$ and $\frac{\pi^2}{6}\left(\frac{n^2+n}{2}\right)-\frac{6}{\pi^2}n\frac{\log(n)}{\log\log(n)}$:

[image]

There is still a clear pattern in the differences function, so I believe that the theoretical formula can be improved even further.

**Is there any theoretical explanation supporting this formula?** It seems much better than the one obtained using abelian partial summation.

Comment: Just to clarify : You search an approximation for the sum of the squarefree numbers (I assume $1$ is included) not exceeding $n$ ? Did you check your asumed expression for , say , $n=10^6$ and $n=10^7$ ?

Comment: The sum must be smaller than $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Do you mean $\frac{6}{\pi^2}\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ ? This seems in fact to work very well.

Comment: @Peter I mean what I said, the partial sum of the first $n$ square-free integers, not the sum of the square-free integers not exceeding $n$. In this case, the sum is greater than $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$.

Comment: The sum of the first $n$ squarefree numbers is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A173143 and the asymptotic $(\pi^2/12)n^2$ is given, but with no discussion or references.

Answer (score 2):

By Abelian partial summation,

$$
\sum_{n=1}^x n 1_{n \text{ square-free}} = \frac{6}{π^2} x^2 + O(x^{3/2}) - \int_1^x 1 \frac{6t}{π^2} dt + O(x^{3/2})
$$

Thus, your asymptotic is correct, and the error term has the order $x^{3/2}$.

EDIT: If you want to sum the first $m$ (changing letters here to avoid notational overload) square-free integers, then you may choose $x = π^2/6 m + O(\sqrt{m})$, so that there are $m$ square-free integers up to $x$, and insert this into the above asymptotic.

Comment: You can get a better error term if you use the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: Interesting trailing comment.  Please consider adding an additional section to your answer where you demonstrate using the Reimann hypothesis to improve the error term (... from someone who has a moderate understanding of Reimann sums, but is totally ignorant of Abelian partial summation).

Comment: Basically, the Riemann hypothesis gives you a better order for the error term of the proportion of square-free integers. This you can then plug into the Abelian summation, about which you may read something here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula

Comment: To be honest , I only know from an improvement of the error term in the case of the prime numbers. Do you have a reference ? Also, you (as I as well) misunderstood the question (see comment above).

Comment: The estimate comes straight from Wikipedia ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Distribution )

Comment: @Cloudscape thanks for your answer! Any idea on why the theoretical formula I have posted seems to improve so much the error term?

Comment: @JuanMoreno By imitating the proof of Wikipedia, I managed to squeeze the error term down to x^(5/4)+ε under the Riemann hypothesis (using Abelian summation and estimates on the Mertens function to bound the error in the main term). I don't really know how to go beyond that.

Comment: I had hoped that I could discover some cancellation in the process, but so far I've failed.

Comment: @Cloudscape thanks for the effort and the interest! Lets see if we find a reasonable explanation of why my theoretical formula works so well, and if it can be improved even better